# Bulleted List hyperlink style Asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" DisplayMode="HyperLink" style="list-style :none" >
```

I am adding list item dynamically to the above bulleted list. How to add style to the href of each list.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the css-class attribute:

declaratively:

```
<style>   
    class1 {  text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; color:#e00000; }
    ... 
</style>

<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" DisplayMode="HyperLink" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem class="class1">a</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem class="class2">b</asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

programmatically:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ListItem listItem = new ListItem("c");
   listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "class1");
   BulletedList1.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```

Comment: I have bulleted list display mode as hyperlink so how i will add class to the href tag?

Comment: Have you tried to define a css class with your appropriate style?

Comment: Yes, i am using a predefined style which is used across the application.

Comment: Mine isn't working. and inside the `ListItem` it's telling me class is not a value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding the listitem dynamically to the BulletList then you can add style this way to listitem's

```
listItem1.Attributes.Add("Class", "NameOfTheClass");
```

OR

```
listItem1.Attributes.Add("style", "YourInlineCss");
```

Comment: It adds class to <li> element not the href section inside <li>

Comment: @ChittaSukla you can write css class for li.a

Comment: @ChittaSukla: when you declare style in your css define it as something like `class1 a{ color:#00f;)`

Comment: I am using predefined style on the application to avoid the future maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

File.css:

```
.href a:link a:visited
{
    color: Red;
}

.href a:hover
{
    color: Yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.href a:active
{
    color: Green;
}
```

Code.aspx:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="nome" DataValueField="id" 
        DisplayMode="HyperLink" CssClass="href">
    </asp:BulletedList>
```

Version interactive:

```
for (int i = 0; i < BulletedList1.Items.Count; i++)
{
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            BulletedList1.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Value = "href";
        }
        else
        {
            BulletedList1.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Value = "other";
        }
}
```

Comment: I can't define my own css. I have to use the predefined css, which is used across organization to avoid the future maintanence.

Comment: Replace href and other by the company css.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by adding a jQuery selector event.

```
$("<%=BulletedList1.ClientID%> li a").each(function() { 
    $(this).addClass('ClassName')
});
```